# How to get out infinite loop

Tags: python

You work for a bakery that sells two items: muffins and cupcakes. The number of muffins and cupcakes in your shop at any given time is stored in the variables  muffins and cupcakes , which have been defined for you. 
Write a program that takes strings from standard input indicating what your customers are buying ("muffin" for a muffin, "cupcake" for a cupcake). If they buy a muffin, decrease muffins by one, and if they buy a cupcake, decrease cupcakes by 1. If there is no more of that baked good left, print ("Out of stock"). 
Once you are done selling, input "0" , and have the program print out the number of muffins and cupcakes remaining, in the form "muffins: 9 cupcakes: 3" (if there were 9 muffins and 3 cupcakes left, for example).

```
to_buy=input()
while to_buy != "0":
if to_buy==muffins and muffins>0:

    muffins-=1
else:
    print("Out of stock")
if to_buy==cupcakes and cupcakes>0:

    cupcakes-=1
else:
    print("Out of stuck")
print("muffins:",muffins,"cupcakes:",cupcakes)
```

The above is the question and the code that i have wrote. When I try to run it, the code kept going into a infinite loop, I don't know why.

Comment: muffins and cupcakes are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> the code kept going into a infinite loop, I don't know why.

```
to_buy=input()
while to_buy != "0":
```

You never change `to_buy`, so the loop continues indefinitely.  For instance, suppose `to_buy` is "3".  Then the while loop condition is True, so execution enters the while loop.  But inside the while loop `to_buy` never changes, so the while loop executes over and over again.

To get around that problem, you can do this:

```
while True:  #Infinite loop

    to_buy = input()
    if to_buy == "0": break  #Terminate the infinite loop

    #Rest of code here
```

Comment: `to_buy` is supposed to indicate either the type of food, or an exit code (`'0'`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Totally irrelevant.

Comment: `to_buy` should never be `'3'` though.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, '3' is just a sample input for the OP to easily understand

Comment: @TigerhawkT3,  Do you know what `input()` does?

Comment: I know what `input()` does, but the user is never supposed to enter a `3`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, A user can enter ANYTHING they want.

Comment: They can, but they shouldn't. This program isn't set up to handle anything other than `cupcake`, `muffin`, or `0`. Suggesting `3` implies (to me, at least) that the purpose of `to_buy` is how many items the user wants to buy, which turns into how many times the loop runs. However, that's not what it's for. Suggesting `3` makes the issue less clear.

Answer (score 0):

this line: `to_buy=input()`

must be inside the `loop`

the variable `to_buy` never changed it's value while looping.. so therefore, it will not exit the loop and it result to ***infinite loop***.

in order to exit the loop. you must change the value of variable `to_buy`.

in Order to do that.

> you must place the input inside the loop

I will suggest also to use a `do while`, so it will process the input first

Comment: It must also be outside the loop, so that the `while` can evaluate it.

Comment: it can still evaluate if he use a `do while`

Answer (score 0):

```
to_buy=input()
while to_buy != "0":
    if to_buy=="muffin":
        if muffins>0:
            muffins-=1
        else:
            print("Out of stock")
    if to_buy=="cupcake":
        if cupcakes>0:
            cupcakes-=1
        else:
            print("Out of stock")
    to_buy=input()
print("muffins:", muffins, "cupcakes:", cupcakes)
```